# Using the numbers 8642 = 9

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Using any calculation in BEDMAS use the numbers 8645 = 9
Numbers can only be repeated once.

Comment: The title doesn't agree with the content.

Comment: Don't edit over your old question, ask a new one instead.

Answer (score 2):

We may have ambiguity here, but I will try to answer both cases. Please note there could be more answers, just that I will list one for each case.
8, 6, 4, 2:

> 8+(6-4)/2 = 8+2/2 = 8+1 = 9

8, 6, 4, 5:

> 6+5-8/4 = 6+5-2 = 11-2 = 9

Answer (score 2):

For the numbers 2,4,6,8 one solution is (6-2)/4+8=9

For the numbers 4,5,6,8 one solution is  8/(6-4)+5=9